# Issue on loading webapp with theme METRONIC admin7 on UIWebView - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview, metronic

I'm using Metronic theme Admin7 and I found an issue when the hamburger menu is clicked on iOS UIWebView.

I'm using Xcode 7 and Objective-C to develop.

The problem occurs at higher devices than the iPhone 4S.
Simulator works.

Print from [issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6BDz.jpg) | Print from [simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oav70.png).

In a test on the iPhone 6 I managed to capture a log, but it does not repeat all the time, but I believe it is related to the problem.

```
Condlink[416:68045] UIAccessibility Error adding -[DOMNode _moveRight:withHistory:]
Condlink[416:68045] UIAccessibility Error adding -[DOMNode _moveLeft:withHistory:]
Condlink[416:68045] UIAccessibility Error adding -[DOMNode _updateSelectionWithTextRange:withAffinityDownstream:]
Condlink[416:68045] UIAccessibility Error adding +[DOMNode safeCategoryBaseClass]
Condlink[416:68045] UIAccessibility Error adding -[UIWebFormAccessory _accessibilityLoadAccessibilityInformation]
Condlink[416:68045] UIAccessibility Error adding -[UIWebFormAccessory initWithFrame:]
Condlink[416:68045] UIAccessibility Error adding +[UIWebFormAccessory safeCategoryBaseClass]
Condlink[416:68045] UIAccessibility Error adding +[UIWebFormSelectPeripheral safeCategoryBaseClass]
Condlink[416:68045] UIAccessibility Error adding +[UIWebFormSelectPeripheral createPeripheralWithDOMHTMLSelectElement:]
Condlink[416:68045] UIAccessibility Error adding -[UIWebSelectSinglePicker _accessibilityServesAsFirstElement]
Condlink[416:68045] UIAccessibility Error adding +[UIWebSelectSinglePicker safeCategoryBaseClass]
Condlink[416:68045] UIAccessibility Error adding -[UIWebSelectMultiplePicker _accessibilityServesAsFirstElement]
Condlink[416:68045] UIAccessibility Error adding +[UIWebSelectMultiplePicker safeCategoryBaseClass]
Condlink[416:68045] UIAccessibility Error adding -[UIWebPlugInView webPlugInStart]
Condlink[416:68045] UIAccessibility Error adding +[UIWebPlugInView safeCategoryBaseClass]
```